# Why is my Facebook application with error 104 ("invalid signature")?

Tags: python, authentication, facebook, cherrypy, pyfacebook

I am trying to develop a Facebook application using PyFacebook (hosted on Google App Engine).  It's an FBML application (runs in a Facebook canvas instead of an iframe).  I'm having problems getting any API calls to function.  The sequence looks like this:

```
fb = facebook.Faceboook(api_key, secret_key)
fb.session_key = cherrypy.request.params['fb_sig_session_key']
fb.uid =cherrypy.request.params['fb_sig_user']
```

Then if I try, for example:

```
user = fb.users.getLoggedInUser()
```

This will fail with:

```
Error 104: Incorrect signature
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  I've verified that the api_key and secret_key are correct (many, many times).  The application has been added to my account.  I've even been able to get a desktop application working; my problem is only with this web-hosted version.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this help?: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Talk:How_Facebook_Authenticates_Your_Application

Comment: I don't think so...that is, I'm not generating the signature myself; the pyfacebook module is doing that.  Since this module appears to work for people in general, I'm assuming the problem is my code.  I guess plan B would be to ditch the module I talk to FB myself, but I'd prefer to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the Facebook application and re-creating it, then configuring my code with the new API key and secret key, resolved this problem.

Comment: You can slso reset the secret without deleting the app, which worked for me.